# Splitting into parts marked by capitals using gsub

Tags: regex, gsub

Using `gsub()` or `substr()` in R I would like to split the following strings

```
s <- c("IntAssisACTG", "IntFullPSYC", "IntAssocSOC")
```

into three subparts

(1) "Int" 
(2) The next set of letters, which begin with the first capital after "Int" and ends before the next capital but of differing lengths (e.g. "Assis", "Full", "Assoc")
(3) The remaining letters, always all capitals but of different lengths (e.g. "ACTG", "PSYC", "SOC")

I want to have the three parts returned as-is, and as a vector (e.g. "Int" "Assis"  "ACTG") and I have read that gsub is better for what I need as it splits while not throwing away the characters that begin each split.

I found this on stack overflow

```
gsub("(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", " ", s, perl=T)
```

And it's getting close to what I want except (i) it splits *all* the capitals in the final segment whereas I need them in one segment (ii) I don't know *how* it works

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the lookahead with a capture group and add a quantifier:

```
gsub("(?!^)([[:upper:]]+)", " $1", s, perl=T)
```

Comment: Thank you @Toto. I think I understand the second capture group. It reads "If one or more upper-case, place the space in front of the back-reference in front of the segment it references". Is that correct? I have no idea how the first group `(?!^)` works. Could you explain it?

Comment: @llewmills: You're right for the uppercases. `(?!^)` is called negative lookbehind, it's a zero length assertion that assume we are not at the begining of the string.You'll find usefull informations here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html